# Want to add a layout in header using Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I am creating a small module in Magento to display a dropdown in header. I have added below code.

```
<reference name="header">
      <block type="page/template_links" name="abc" before="store_language" as="abc" template="abc/abc.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

With this code I am unable to view my `abc.phtml` file content in header.

I dont want to use below code.

`echo $this->getChildHtml('abc')`

Please help me How I can add my code without this function in my magento header.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone can help me............? Its urgent for me...... I am new in magento....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add to output="toHtml" as new attribute to the block.

But I'm not sure if the abc.phtml is going to show I the place you want.

Let me know if this tip worked.

Best,
GrinGo.

Comment: output="toHtml" This code add my content before </body> tag. I want to place my code inside the header before top.link.

Comment: @HiraSingh Then the functionality is working fine. You need to change the location of calling your block. If you want to call inside the <div class="header">, then you need to call your block from page/html/header.phtml. Accordingly you need to make modifications in layout file also..

Comment: I dont want to make change in my theme files or base files. I dont want to use $this->getChildHtml('abc') function in my header.phtml file. I just want to display my content with the help of my extension's xml or block file.

Comment: I think the way you want only using XML is no possible from my point of view.

Comment: Actually I dont want to edit any magento file. I want to do this with extension's file only... If you know any method to do this then must share with me. This will be helpful for me.....

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new static block and call it, should work as an alternative

```
<div id="NAME"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('BLOCK')->toHtml() ?></div>
```